# How to enter a list of strings as a parameter?

Tags: powershell, parameters

I've got a cmdlet where I accept a list of strings as a parameter, defined in a c# class like this:

```cs
[Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
public List<string> AllowedScopes;
```

So when I call my command called `Add-Client`, how do I provide a list of strings in PowerPhell? I've tried this (each line is a different approach):

```bsh
-AllowedScopes scope1, scope2, scope3
-AllowedScopes [scope1, scope2, scope3]
-AllowedScopes {scope1, scope2, scope3}
-AllowedScopes {"scope1", "scope2", "scope3"}
```

But I always just get one entry in my list "AllowedScopes" which contains of the full string entered after the AllowedScopes parameter name.

I cannot find anything about this easily so I guess I'm asking the wrong question.

I can of course have the AllowedScopes parameter be a simple string and then do something like this:

```cs
var AllowedScopesAsList = this.AllowedScopes.Split(',').ToList();
```

But I think that this should be something that's provided by powershell (since it provides so much other useful features keeping me from implementing the whole user-interaction part of my cmdlet)

**Edit:** Here is the full contents of my cmdlet C#-class:

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace MyCmdlets
{
    [Cmdlet("Add", "Client")]
    public class AddClient : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
        public List<string> AllowedScopes;

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            AllowedScopes.ForEach(a => WriteObject(a));
        }
    }
}
```

With this if I try entering the list like one of the answers said:

```bsh
Add-Client -AllowedScopes @('scope1', 'scope2')
```

I get this output:

```
<pre>
scope1
scope2
</pre>
```

Which is as expected.

But it does not work, if I provide the parameter when being asked for it by PowerShell, like this:

```
<pre>
PS> <b>Add-Client</b> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Cmdlet Add-Client at CommandPipelineposition 1
Enter the values for the following parameter:
AllowedScopes[0]: <b>@('scope1','scope2')</b> <kbd>Enter</kbd>
AllowedScopes[1]: <kbd>Enter</kbd>
</pre>
```

Now the output is this:

```bsh
@('scope1','scope2')
```

Even if I enter the scopes there one by one it still results in the list receiving just one child:

```
<pre>
AllowedScopes[0]: <b>'scope1'</b>
AllowedScopes[1]: <b>'scope2'</b>
AllowedScopes[2]:
</pre>
```

Output:

```
<pre>
'scope1' 'scope2'
</pre>
```

/edit2:
I've uploaded a video so you can see how powershell is not behaving as expected (at least I think it's not):

[Youtube-Video with powershell-misbehavior](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ISgu9tkz7pU)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You appear to have hit a **[*bug*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7692)** that affects Windows PowerShell as of v5.1 and PowerShell Core as of v6.1.0

PowerShell's automatic prompting unexpectedly passes individually entered elements to bind to parameter `-AllowedScopes` as a *single* string that is the *concatenation* of the individual elements, separated with spaces.
By contrast, passing an array of values from the command line - e.g.,
`-AllowedScopes scope1, scope2, scope3` - works correctly.

The **bug is triggered by your parameter being defined as `List<string>`** rather than as `string[]`.
Arguably, `string[]` is the better choice in this case anyway, so the **workaround is to declare your `-AllowedScopes` parameter as `string[]` (array)**:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @'
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Management.Automation;

namespace MyCmdlets
{
    [Cmdlet("Add", "Client")]
    public class AddClient : Cmdlet
    {
        [Parameter(Mandatory = true)]
        // Use string[] instead of List<string>
        public string[] AllowedScopes;

        protected override void ProcessRecord()
        {
            foreach (var scope in AllowedScopes) {
                WriteObject(scope);
            }
        }
    }
}
'@ -PassThru | ForEach-Object Assembly | Import-Module

# Let PowerShell prompt for -AllowedScopes
# Due to use of string[] rather than List<string>, the individually entered
# elements are now correctly passed as an array.
Add-Client
```

Note that the bug does *not* surface if a type other than `string` is used for the generic list.

---

**Original answer with general information**:

Your code works as designed and `-AllowedScopes scope1, scope2, scope3` is indeed the way to pass multiple list elements:

`scope1, scope2, scope3` uses `,`, the array-construction operator, to construct a 3-element array that is bound to the `-AllowedScopes` parameter and converted to a `List<string>` instance.

PowerShell's automatic prompting mechanism for mandatory parameters for which no arguments were passed on the command line works as designed too:

For a collection-typed parameter such as `-AllowedScopes`:

- the elements of the collection are prompted for *individually*,
- and you signal the end of the input by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> once more after having submitted the last element.

If you want to allow users to pass all elements with a *single* prompt, you must implement custom logic:

- Declare `-AllowedScopes` as a *single* string so that user can pass something like
  `'scope1, scope2, scope3'`
- Split the string value received into the embedded elements inside your cmdlet.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-AllowedScopes @('scope1', 'scope2', 'scope3')`

`@` construct indicates an array, so `@(item,item,item,..)` makes an array of values.

Comment: Thank you, this works if I provide the parameter directly, like so:  Add-Client -AllowedScopes @('scope1', 'scope2')  ----  But it does not work, if I provide the parameter when being asked for it by powershell, like this: Add-Client <Enter>

Cmdlet Add-Client at CommandPipelineposition 1
Enter the values for the following parameter:
AllowedScopes[0]: @('scope1','scope2')
AllowedScopes[1]: <Enter> ---- In this case it simply is one string again.

Comment: seems like AllowedScopes accepts an array of values [type[]]. You will be always proposed to input items separated. You could rewrite your function or just wrap up it with another one to split input string and continue. Something like this: function Add-Client-Helper
{param([String]$AllowedScopes)
    foreach ($scope in @([regex]::Split($AllowedScopes,','))){
        Add-Client -AllowedScopes $scope
    }
}

Comment: The array subexpression operator is `@()`, not just `@`. `@` by itself is ambiguous and can indicate either an array subexpression(`@(...)`), a hashtable construct (`@{...}`), or a splatting operation (`@variable`), depending on what character it precedes.

Comment: It is `,`, the _array construction_ operator that _creates_ an array (`item,item,item,...`); by contrast, `@(...)`, the _array subexpression_ operator _guarantees_ that the output from one or more statements is an array. Up to v5.0, `@(item,item,item,...)` actually creates an - unnecessary - copy of the array already constructed by `item,item,item,...` itself; in PSv5.1+, use of `@(...)` with an array literal (that doesn't use a cast) is simply optimized away.